# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error while trying to use Edge and MicrosoftWebDriver.exe through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver, microsoft-webdriver

I created a script in Python, which scraps the Altium's website and gathers information regarding license usage. At this moment, I am using ChromeDriver, but I sometimes get errors due to the network being slow at different times of the day. I used the same script using the MicrosoftWebDriver (Edge) on my Personal Computer and I received no errors. When you launch the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe (downloaded from their website) it should open Edge, but when I use my company's laptop, nothing happens (see attached picture).

Is there any chance I can fix this? Is this happening as a result of the port being blocked?

This is the code I am using for selecting the webdriver:

```
browser = webdriver.Edge(r'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\Altium_Python\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
```

And this is the "error" I get:

[image]

And nothing happens after this...

The Python's Shell says this:

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ALTIUM_WORK\Altium_Python\Altium_H1.py", line 172, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Edge(r'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\Altium_Python\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 208, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the *argument* `executable_path` as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\Altium_Python\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

This what solved the problem...

Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode -> ENABLED

Answer (score 0):

```
browser = webdriver.Edge(r'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\Altium_Python\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
```

This is not working because in your office laptop `User Account Control settings` is `Turned Off`.

[image]

You need turned On `User Account Control settings` and restart your machine and then run your code.It will work as expected.

[image]

To go to path on OS :

```
Control Panel-->All Control Panel Items-->User Accounts--> Change User Account Control settings
```

[image]